# HTC One M8, Marshmallow: apps list not working (Playstore install error: 505)

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, htc-one-m8

HTC Recently pushed Android 6.0 to my HTC One M8. (NL)
The update installed without any problems, but I'm now experiencing a few bugs.

- I can not access the APPS list, it gives me the 'please wait' icon. (Settings -> Apps)
- A lot of apps can't be installed since the update. (Playstore error: 505)

  - I've tried to clear the cache of the Play store and rebooted the device.
  - I've re-added my google account
  - But still persists.

What I've done after the update is.. I formatted the external SD to internal storage and rebooted the device.

- The device is running a stock rom, official rom from HTC.
- The device never has been rebooted.
- The device has nothing third party flashed on it.

-- Sincerely Jordy.

Comment: I have the same problem. I found leaving the app list in the play store open it loads after a min or two. But that only allows you to one app at a time

Comment: A factory reset might resolve this, but then you lose all your data (that isn't backed up/synced).